# Adding a fixed date to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading some data and creating a dataframe with from_records in which the data contains a text timestamp HH:MM:SS:000000. I can convert to timeseries with `pd.to_datetime(data.timestamp, format='%H:%M:%S:%f')`. I know the date of the file from the filename. What is a pythonic and performant way to insert the date (and eventually set it as the index)?

Data looks like:

```
12:00:00:000000 100
12:00:01:123456 200
12:00:02:000000 300
```

Without the date inserted I get a dataframe that looks like:

```
1900-01-01 12:00:00.000000 100
1900-01-01 12:00:01.123456 200
1900-01-01 12:00:02.000000 300
```

And what I'd want is (given `date = datetime.date(2017, 6, 28)`:

```
2017-06-28 12:00:00.000000 100
2017-06-28 12:00:01.123456 200
2017-06-28 12:00:02.000000 300
```

`pd.to_datetime` `origin` arg sounded like what I want, but it requires the input as a numeric timestamp rather than a string.

Comment: You should be able to just do `df.index += date`. That worked for me anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create string by `strftime` from date and add it to column `time`:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + df['time'],
                                format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

print (df)
              time    A                   datetime
0  12:00:00:000000  100 2017-06-28 12:00:00.000000
1  12:00:01:123456  200 2017-06-28 12:00:01.123456
2  12:00:02:000000  300 2017-06-28 12:00:02.000000
```

And for index:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + df['time'],
                                format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

print (df)
                                       time    A
time                                            
2017-06-28 12:00:00.000000  12:00:00:000000  100
2017-06-28 12:00:01.123456  12:00:01:123456  200
2017-06-28 12:00:02.000000  12:00:02:000000  300
```

Another solution:

```
date = datetime.date(2017, 6, 28)
days = date - datetime.date(1900, 1, 1)

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%H:%M:%S:%f') + 
                 pd.to_timedelta(days, unit='d')

print (df)
              time    A                   datetime
0  12:00:00:000000  100 2017-06-28 12:00:00.000000
1  12:00:01:123456  200 2017-06-28 12:00:01.123456
2  12:00:02:000000  300 2017-06-28 12:00:02.000000
```

Comment: Functionally that works but is there a faster way that doesn't require the date to be parsed to and from a string? (I have tens of millions of rows).

Comment: What about another solution?

Comment: @jezreal Awesome! It would however be great, if you could specify the date offset, when using `read_csv()` and similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with, based on @jezrael's 'Another' answer:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, format='%H:%M:%S:%f')
days = date - df.index[0].date()
df.index += pd.to_timedelta(days, unit='d')
```